# supersized + ie8/7 again

Tags: internet-explorer-8, modernizr, supersized

I got an old problem but the common solutions for that not work. I combined supersized plugin with modernizr media queries.

Everything works fine in all normal browsers and even ie 9. But IE8/IE7 fails to load supersized plugin. I even removed the trailing comma after image list.

Code below. Any suggestions?

```
    Modernizr.load([
            {
                test:Modernizr.mq('only screen and (min-width: 600px)'),
                yep:['/js/supersized/js/supersized.core.3.2.1.min.js','/js/supersized/css/supersized.core.css'],
                complete: function() {
                    if(Modernizr.mq('only screen and (min-width:600px)')) {
                        jQuery(function($){
                            $.supersized({
                                fit_portrait: true,
                                slides  : [
                                    {image : '/img/sample.jpg', title : 'sample'}
                                ]
                                });
                        }); 
                    };
                }
            }
        ]);
```

Kind regards,
Arek

Comment: can this be a problem with $ in jQuery(function($){ $.supersized({.....?

Answer (score 0):

Is the html5 shiv added in your modernizr build. I've had problems with the latest version of supersized in ie8 and below, because it the plugins tries to append elements to an aside-element. But in ie8(& below) when there is no html5-shiv the aside elements is not correctly recognized in your javascript, erroring out and failing miserably on the append-function.

Comment: yep, i tried different combinations of modrnizr build. I got media queries and html5 shiv. I also included css3-mediaqueries.js to be sure that it works for ie browser. Still nothing. Strange thing is that i got no error in the console.